# How to pass route params to vuex getter?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I tried [How to get Vue Router Params in Vuex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824234/how-to-get-vue-router-params-in-vuex), but doesn't seem to work.

getter:

```
getAssetById: state => id => {
      return state.assets.find(asset => asset.id === id)
    }
```

component:

```
<div class="card padding-35 box-shadow ">
        //this on is OK
        {{ assetId }}

        {{ asset }}
      </div>

 computed: {
    assetId() {
      return this.$route.params.id
    },
    asset() {
      //this doesn't work
      return this.$store.getters.getAssetById(assetId)
    }
    asset() {
      //this work
      return this.$store.getters.getAssetById(1)
    }
  }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should've thinked about it earlier, converting to int solved the problem:

```
assetId() {
      return parseInt(this.$route.params.id)
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to change the return to `this.$store.getters.getAssetById(this.assetId)`

Comment: I have it like that, just forgot to type in here, sorry